# C# Filling double[][] manually

Tags: c#, arrays

I am just trying out a source code. 
This source code has the following line:

```
double[][] inputs = sourceMatrix.Submatrix(null, 0, 1).ToArray();
```

Originally, this "inputs" is filled using a matrix, but I am still too inexperienced to use this matrix. I would first like to test it with some hand-coded values.

Could anybody please tell me how to populate double[][] with some values?

I am not really experienced with C# yet. I guess that [][] means a threedimensional array.

In VB6 I would simply say

```
Redim inputs(2,2)
```

and then:

```
inputs(0,0) = 64
inputs(0,1) = 92
inputs(0,2) = 33
inputs(1,0) = 4
inputs(1,1) = 84
inputs(1,2) = 449
```

etc...

But I guess it is not that easy in C#.
If anybody could help, I would be really glad.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would `[][]` mean *three* dimensions? If you're going to repopulate the data completely, why bother calling `Submatrix` in the first place? I suggest you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx - it would be much better to focus on learning about arrays *in general* than just the population aspect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a `double[][]` is a *jagged array* - it is an array of arrays. To fill that you would fill the outer array with a set of `double[]` arrays. However, I expect you want a *rectangular* array: `double[,]`, for example `new double[3,2]`. There is a short-hand for initializing such arrays:

```
double[,] data = new double[2, 3] { { 64, 92, 33 }, { 4, 84, 449 } };
double val = data[1, 2]; // 449.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of arrays. So you should initialize them like this:

```
double[][] inputs = new double[][]
    {
        new double[] { 1, 2, 3 },
        new double[] { 4, 5, 6 },
        new double[] { 7, 8, 9 }
    };
```

If you had a two dimentional array (`inputs[,]`) then it would be:

```
double[,] inputs = new double[,]
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };
```

But as Jon Skeet said, reading about arrays is the first thing you should do.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it very simple:

```
double[][] inputs = new double[3][];
inputs[0] = new double[3];
inputs[1] = new double[3];
inputs[2] = new double[3];

inputs[0][0] = 1;
inputs[0][1] = 2;
inputs[0][2] = 3;
inputs[1][0] = 4;
inputs[1][1] = 5;
inputs[1][2] = 6;
inputs[2][0] = 7;
inputs[2][1] = 8;
inputs[2][2] = 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using `double[,]` this is what you need [Arrays](http://www.functionx.com/csharp3/Lesson23.htm)

Answer (score 0):

double[][] is a jagged array.
You probably mean double[,] which is two dimensional array.

Initializing a two dimensional array:

```
double[,] matrix = new double[3,2] = {{1,2} {3,4}, {4,5}}
```

You already have examples for initializing jagged arrays, from the other answers.

The difference between jagged and true multidimensional arrays in practice is jagged arrays are arrays of arrays so it is possible for them not to be rectangular, i.e. a matrix, hence jagged:

```
double[][] jagged = new double[2]
                   {
                       new double[4],
                       new double[2]
                    };
```

The way they are layed out in memory is also different. A multidimensional array is a single reference to a contiguous memory space. Jagged arrays are true array of arrays.

Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)